# Describing fiber products in stable $\infty$-categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, infinity-categories, higher-algebra

Let $f\colon X \rightarrow Z$ and $g\colon Y \rightarrow Z$ be two morphisms in a stable infinity category $\mathcal{C}$. How does one show that the $\infty$-categorical fiber product $X \times_Z Y$ can be canonically identified with the fiber of the map $f - g \colon X \oplus Y \rightarrow Z$?

I am sure that the question is quite basic (for instance, something quite similar is used implicitly in the proof of Proposition 1.1.3.4 of Lurie's "Higher algebra"), but I would nevertheless appreciate an explanation. The type of answer I am *not* looking for is "this is trivial consequence of the definitions" because I believe that there is something to check: $X \times_Z Y$ makes sense in any $\infty$-category that has fiber products, whereas the other description uses the stability assumption.

While we are at it, let me ask a related bonus question: with $f$ and $g$ as above, suppose that we also have maps $a\colon F \rightarrow X$ and $b\colon F \rightarrow Y$ that make the evident diagram commute and such that $\mathrm{fib}(a) \simeq \mathrm{fib}(g)$ via the induced map (a five lemma type of setting where one of the vertical maps is an isomorphism). Do these conditions imply that the map $F \rightarrow X \times_Z Y$ is an isomorphism?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In fact what you need is that your ∞-category is *additive* (i.e. that it has direct sums and that the canonical commutative monoid structure on the mapping spaces is group-like). All stable categories are additive, so I'll just prove it in this case.

**Step 1**: The pullback $X\times_Z Y$ is equivalent to the pullback $(X\times Y)\times_{Z\times Z}Z$. This fact is true in every ∞-category with finite limits

I'm sure there are many ways of proving this. One way of doing it (thanks to Omar Antolín-Camarena for the idea) is to consider the diagram

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
Y @>>> Z @<<< Z\\
@VVV @VVV @VVV\\
\ast @>>> \ast @<<<  Z\\
@AAA @AAA @AAA\\
X @>>> Z @<<< Z 
\end{CD}\,,$$

where $\ast$ is the terminal object. Taking the limit first in the horizontal direction and the in the vertical direction we obtain $X\times_Z Y$, while taking the limits in the opposite order we obtain $(X\times Y)\times_{Z\times Z}Z$. Since both methods compute the limit of the whole diagram, the two objects must be equivalent.

**Step 2**: The diagonal $Z\to Z\oplus Z$ is the fiber of the "difference" map $Z\oplus Z\xrightarrow{(1_Z,-1_Z)} Z$

This is where we use the additivity hypothesis. Recall that one way of phrasing that the ∞-category is additive is that the shear map
$$Z\oplus Z\xrightarrow{\left(\substack{1\, 1\\ 0\, 1}\right)} Z\oplus Z$$
is an equivalence. Then there is an equivalence of sequences
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
Z @>{\left(\substack{0\\1}\right)}>> Z\oplus Z @>{(1\,0)}>> Z\\
@| @V{\left(\substack{1\,1\\0\,1}\right)}VV @|\\
Z @>{\left(\substack{1\\1}\right)}>> Z\oplus Z @>{(1\,-1)}>> Z
\end{CD}$$
Since the top one is a fiber sequence, so is the bottom one.

**Step 3** Profit!

Let us consider the following diagram
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X\times_Z Y @>>> Z @>>> 0\\
@VVV @V{\left(\substack{1\\1}\right)}VV @VVV\\
X\oplus Y @>{(f\,g)}>> Z\oplus Z @>{(1\,-1)}>> Z
\end{CD}$$
Since the left and right squares are cartesian (by step 1 and 2), so is the big one, which was the thesis.

---

*Bonus question:* In every $\infty$-category with finite limits, if you have a square of pointed objects
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
F @>{a}>> X\\
@V{b}VV @V{f}VV\\
Y @>{g}>> Z
\end{CD}
$$
there is a canonical equivalence between the fiber of the map $F\to X\times_Z Y$ and the fiber of the induced map $\mathrm{fib}(a)→\mathrm{fib}(g)$. This can be proven as before, by considering the diagram
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\ast @>>> X @<<{a}< F\\
@VVV @V{f}VV @V{b}VV\\
\ast @>>> Z @<<{g}<  Y\\
@AAA @A{g}AA @AA{1_Y}A\\
\ast @>>> Y @<{1_Y}<< Y
\end{CD}\,,$$
and taking the limit in the two directions (you can find more details in the first section of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.7271)). Incidentally this object is called the *total fiber* of the square.

Since in a stable ∞-category a map is an equivalence iff the fiber is trivial, this gives an affermative answer to your query.

Comment: Thank you, this is very useful. Do you happen to also know the answer to the bonus question?

Comment: @QuestionMachine Let me add a quick remark

Comment: For step 1 you can also use that pullbacks commute will pullbacks: $(X \times Y) \times_{Z \times Z} Z \simeq$ $(X \times_1 Y) \times_{Z \times_1 Z} (Z \times_Z Z) \simeq^\ast$ $(X \times_Z Z) \times_{1 \times_1 Z} (Y \times_Z Z) \simeq$ $X \times_Z Y$, where $1$ is terminal and the equivalence labelled $\ast$ is the commutation step.

Comment: @OmarAntolín-Camarena That's a nice way of seeing it! I'm thinking of adding a variant of that proof to my answer

Comment: @DenisNardin I'll check in later to see what variant you had in mind. I really like these little tricks and was happy to see your proof of step 1 (since I only knew the proof I mentioned).

Comment: @OmarAntolín-Camarena If you are interested I can give a more conceptual explanation: the category $I_n$ is the poset of chains of nonempty subsets of $\{1,..,n\}$. There is a cofinal functor $I_n→P_{\neq\varnothing}\{1,..,n\}$ sending every chain to its maximal element and a right fibration $I_n→P_{\neq\varnothing}\{1,..,n\}$ sending every chain to the subset given by the cardinalities of the elements of the chain. The diagram I used is the case $n=2$. This is helpful when your original cube has a $G$-action for a finite group $G$, because this allows you to remove the action.

Comment: @DenisNardin Thanks for the explanation about $I_n$! And as for the variant of the commutation proof: what you wrote is what you'd see on my blackboard, I flattened it out to a single line to fit comfortably in a comment. :)

Comment: Is $\mathrm{fib}(a)→\mathrm{fib}(g)$ meant to be $\mathrm{fib}(f)→\mathrm{fib}(g)$?

Comment: @DavidRoberts No, it's the map induced between two parallel arrows of the square.

Comment: On *the fibers* of two parallel arrows of the square, sorry

Comment: @DenisNardin ah, I didn't bother to click through to see the details; I gather the map $a$ is defined somewhere?

Comment: @DavidRoberts Look at the last paragraph of the question

Comment: @Denis thanks for expanding your answer!

Answer (score 3):

A proof of this in the context of stable derivators can be found in my paper [Mayer-Vietoris sequences in stable derivators](https://arxiv.org/abs/1306.2072) with Moritz Groth and Kate Ponto.  It is rather more verbose than Denis's, but one reason for that is that it's intended to be fully precise.  In an $\infty$-category, of course, you can't actually just write down some objects and arrows and have a "diagram"; there are coherences that need to be produced too, and kept track of all the way through.  Derivators are a way of forcing oneself to remember that.  (With that said, it's quite possible that if Denis's proof were made precise it would still be shorter than ours.)

Comment: If Denis’s answer is to be considered imprecise, then it would be hard to find a single precise statement in the mathematical literature.

Comment: I'll admit that I skimped in specifying the homotopies, but if you look at the diagrams I wrote there are only two kind of homotopies needed to be specified: homotopies between maps to the terminal object (where you have only one choice), and the defining homotopy for the map $-1:Z→Z$ (a nullhomotopy of $1-1$). Note that $-1$ is essentially defined so that the second square in step 2 commutes. I agree that normally one needs to be careful in specifying what you mean, but here it seems superfluous.

Comment: @DenisNardin I would say there is more,  For instance, it's not immediately obvious to me what it means to "take the limit in the horizontal/vertical direction" of the first diagram, maybe a right Kan extension; but whatever that is, the process produces a 3- or 4-dimensional diagram with a bunch more coherences in it.  One then needs to identify not just the objects appearing in the first sets of pullbacks -- up to equivalence -- but also the morphisms between them as being, e.g., equivalent to the diagonal morphism $Z\to Z\times Z$ or whichever other morphisms one wants.

Comment: Also a "fiber sequence" in an $\infty$-category is not just a pair of composable morphisms with some property, but equipped with the structure of a homotopy relating their composite to the (or "a") zero morphism, often formalized as a commuting square with a zero object at one corner -- which you in fact used in step 3.  Thus, a morphism of sequences is not just a pair of commuting squares but a commutative cube.  Also, the homotopies in the first squares in steps 2 and 3 are neither of the sorts you mentioned in your comment.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken all the cohérences follow trivially from what I have described via universal properties (e.g. you can identify the map $Z\to Z\times Z $ with the diagonal by seeing that its composition with the projections are the horizontal arrows $Z\to Z $ on the right column of my first diagram) By taking the limit first in one direction and then in another I just mean that there is a natural equivalence $\lim_{I\times J} F \cong \lim_I \lim_I F $  for every functor $F:I\times J\to C$, no other coherences needed (beyond of course the definition  of F)

Comment: Regarding what a fiber sequence is, I'm well aware of it. I'll confess I did not want to do a more complicated diagram ('cause AMScd is hard to use) but I am copying the nullhomotopy from the top row to the bottom row via the equivalence. I could have done a more careful analysis, but the question did not ask to explicitly identify the nullhomotopy of the fiber sequence after all :)

Comment: @DenisNardin Well, the whole point of writing out a proof is to make sure that you are *not* mistaken.  (-:  I'm aware that no pencil-and-paper proof is ever completely rigorous, and that different communities of mathematicians have different standards of rigor.  And I'm probably hypersensitive to these issues because these days I spend a lot of time in the homotopy type theory community, where we work with higher homotopy structure but where many proofs are computer-formalized, making it necessary to be absolutely precise.

Comment: However, that very experience, and in particular seeing how much work it can be to actually formalize arguments involving higher homotopies, is part of what makes me uncomfotable with this level of handwaving in $\infty$-category theory.

Comment: @MikeShulman I agree that this is a very tricky thing (and many a mistake were made by careless people forgetting the higher homotopies), but I think we cannot write papers as if they were computer-formalized: they'd be unreadable by actual human beings (and many papers are nigh-unreadable as it is). At some point you'd have to either believe me that I checked that all the issues I'm declaring trivial are actually trivial (and I did check),or check for yourself.If you want to continue this discussion I'd be happy to show you (in chat) in painstaking detail how to formalize every missing detail

Comment: @DenisNardin Oh, I believe it's true.  And I don't even necessarily object to the omission of details.  (In fact if you did actually check them all yourself, I'm impressed!)  I think what bothers me is more the lack of any mention of the fact that details were omitted.